# Rotate theta=0 on matplotlib polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

data_theta = range(10,171,10)

data_theta_rad = []
for i in data_theta:
    data_theta_rad.append(float(i)*np.pi/180.0)

data_r = random.sample(range(70, 90), 17)

print data_theta
print data_r

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(data_theta_rad, data_r, color='r', linewidth=3)
ax.set_rmax(95)
# ax.set_rmin(70.0)
ax.grid(True)

ax.set_title("Example", va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

...which produces something like this:
[image]

...but I would like to set theta=0 to the 'West'. So something like:

[image]

Any ideas how to do this with matplotlib (I made the pic below in powerpoint) ?

Comment: A small side note: `numpy` provides handy functions for angle conversions: `data_theta_rad = np.radians(data_theta)`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Simply use:

```
ax.set_theta_zero_location("W")
```

More info in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/projections_api.html?highlight=set_theta_zero#matplotlib.projections.polar.PolarAxes.set_theta_zero_location) of matplotlib.

Comment: i get: AttributeError: 'PolarAxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_theta_zero_location'...maybe my module is not up to date???

Comment: Whats version of matplotlib are you using? You might have to update, I'm using 1.3.1 and it works fine.

Comment: i'm a little embarassed to say, but I don't know how to find this out

Answer (score 18):

A more flexible way:

`ax.set_theta_offset(pi)`

You can rotate the axis arbitrarily, just replace `pi` with the angle you want.