# Circular histogram with fitted Von Mises Distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib

For the past days I've been trying to plot circular data with python, by constructing a circular histogram ranging from 0 to 2pi and fitting a Von Mises Distribution. What I really want to achieve is this:

1. Directional data with fitted Von-Mises Distribution. This plot was constructed with Matplotlib, Scipy and Numpy and can be found at: http://jpktd.blogspot.com/2012/11/polar-histogram.html

[image]

2. This plot was produced using R, but gives the idea of what I want to plot. It can be found here: https://www.zeileis.org/news/circtree/

[image]

**WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR:**

```
from scipy.special import i0  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyploy as plt

# From my data I fitted a Von-Mises distribution, calculating Mu and Kappa. 
mu = -0.343
kappa = 10.432

# Construct random Von-Mises distribution based on Mu and Kappa values
r = np.random.vonmises(mu, kappa, 1000)

# Adjust Von-Mises curve from fitted data
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num=501)
y = np.exp(kappa*np.cos(x-mu))/(2*np.pi*i0(kappa)) 

# Adjuste x limits and labels
plt.xlim(-np.pi, np.pi)
plt.xticks([-np.pi, -np.pi/2, 0, np.pi/2, np.pi], 
labels=[r'$-\pi$ (0º)', r'$-\frac{\pi}{2}$ (90º)', '0 (180º)', r'$\frac{\pi}{2}$ (270º)', r'$\pi$'])

# Plot adjusted Von-Mises function as line
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=2, color='red', zorder=3

# Plot distribution 
plt.hist(r, density=True,  bins=20, alpha=1, edgecolor='white');
plt.title('Slaty Cleavage Strike', fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)
```

[image]

**My attempt to plot a circular histogram** based on questions such as, [Circular / polar histogram in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562364/circular-polar-histogram-in-python)

```
# From the data above (mu, kappa, x and y):

theta = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num=50, endpoint=False)
radii = np.exp(kappa*np.cos(theta-mu))/(2*np.pi*i0(kappa)) 

# Bin width?
width = (2*np.pi) / 50

# Construct ax with polar projection
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

# Set Zero to North
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

# Plot bars:
bars = ax.bar(x = theta, height = radii, width=width)
# Plot Line:
line = ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=1, color='red', zorder=3) 
 
# Grid settings
ax.set_rgrids(np.arange(1, 1.6, 0.5), angle=0, weight= 'black');
```

[image]

**Notes:**

- My circular histogram plotted my data at wrong direction, at a 180 degrees difference: compare both histograms. **See Edit 1**
- I believe this might have to do with scipy.stats.vonmises which is defined defined on [-pi,pi] https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.vonmises.html **See Edit 1**
- My data originally varied between [0,2pi]. I converted to [-pi,pi] in order to fit a Von Mises and calculate Mu and Kappa. **See Edit 1**

I really would like to plot my data as one of the first plots. My data is geological directional data (Azimuth). Does someone have any ideas?
PS. Sorry for the long post. I hope this is helpful at least

## EDIT 1:

Going through the comments I realized that a few people were confused about the data whether ranging from `[0,2pi]` or `[-pi,pi]`. I realized that the wrong direction plotted in my Circular Histogram came from the following:

1. My original data (geological data) ranges between `[0,2pi]`, i.e. 0 to 360 degrees;
2. However, scipy.stats.vonmises calculates the probability density function in `[-pi, pi]`;
3. I subtracted pi from my data, in order to use scipy.stats.vonmises `my_data - pi`;
4. Once `Mu` and `Kappa` were calculated (CORRECTELY), I added `pi` to the `Mu` value, to recover original orientation, now once again ranging between `[0,2pi]`.
5. Now, my data is correctly oriented to South East:

[image]

```
# Add pi to fitted Mu. 
mu = - 0.343 + np.pi
kappa = 10.432

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num=501)
y = np.exp(kappa*np.cos(x-mu))/(2*np.pi*i0(kappa)) 

theta = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num=50, endpoint=False)
radii = np.exp(kappa*np.cos(theta-mu))/(2*np.pi*i0(kappa)) 

# Bin width?
width = (2*np.pi) / 50

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

# Angles increase clockwise from North
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

bars = ax.bar(x = theta, height = radii, width=width)

line = ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=1, color='red', zorder=3) 

ax.set_rgrids(np.arange(1, 1.6, 0.5), angle=0, weight= 'black');
```

## Edit 2

As suggested at the comments of accepted Answer, the tricks was changing `y_lim`, as follows:

[image]

```
# SE DIRECTION
mu = - 0.343 + np.pi
kappa = 10.432


x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num=501)
y = np.exp(kappa*np.cos(x-mu))/(2*np.pi*i0(kappa)) 

theta = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num=50, endpoint=False)
radii = np.exp(kappa*np.cos(theta-mu))/(2*np.pi*i0(kappa)) 

# PLOT
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

# Bin width?
width = (2*np.pi) / 50

# Angles increase clockwise from North
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N'); ax.set_theta_direction(-1);

bars = ax.bar(x=theta, height = radii, width=width, bottom=0)

# Plot Line
line = ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=2, color='firebrick', zorder=3 ) 

# 'Trick': This will display Zero as a circle. Fitted Von-Mises function will lie along zero.
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5);

ax.set_rgrids(np.arange(0, 1.6, 0.5), angle=60, weight= 'bold',
             labels=np.arange(0,1.6,0.5));
```

## Final Note:

- The histogram provided is already normalized, hence it can be plotted with the vM distribution at the same scale.

Comment: With the parameters you reported (`mu = -0.343` and `kappa = 10.432`) the circular histogram that you show looks completely reasonable.

Comment: @gboffi True. I have to figure it out how to adapt/convert (?) to the orientation as my first histogram (which is the correct one)

Comment: Is [this question and the relative answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906510/rotate-theta-0-on-matplotlib-polar-plot) what you need?

Comment: rotating `theta_offset` rotates the histogram as a whole. The orientation in the circular is somehow wrong and  different from the first histogram

Comment: Maybe `ax.set_theta_direction(-1)` ?

Comment: The orientation is fixed by changing `ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')` (north) to `ax.set_theta_zero_location('E')` (east)

Comment: I really like that you posted all your code and included images in the question, that really helped.

Comment: @gboffi I edited the question I think I fixed the issue regarding the proper orientation

Comment: Regarding the last remaing question, you need the modified Bessel function of order 0, `from scipy.special import iv` and you can write `d = np.exp(κ*np.cos(θ-μ))/(2*np.pi*iv(0, κ))` (`d` for probability _d_istribution)

Comment: BTW you have either to normalize the histogram or to multiply the vM distribution by the numerosity of the sample

Comment: @gboffi This is something that's really bugging me. Do you mind explaining a little be more? I'm not sure If I fully understood.

Comment: The integral of the probability distribution is 1, the sum of the observations is N, to represent the distribution and the histogram on the same graph with the same scale you have to normalize the histogram, or multiply the distribution by N. ፨ Re the definition of the vM probability distribution, I've just read the wikipidia page.

Comment: @gboffi I calculated the area under the curve of red line and the integral was 1. Since, Both Y (red line) and radii (bars) are computed in the same way, do I really need to normalize the histogram?

Comment: From your plots, it looks like the histogram is already normalized, isn't it?

Comment: @gboffi yes. The histograms are normalized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I achieved:

[image]

I'm not entirely sure if you wanted x to range from `[-pi,pi]` or `[0,2pi]`. If you want the range `[0,2pi]` instead, just comment out the lines `ax.set_xlim` and `ax.set_xticks`.

```py
from scipy.special import i0
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# From my data I fitted a Von-Mises distribution, calculating Mu and Kappa.
mu = -0.343
kappa = 10.432

# Construct random Von-Mises distribution based on Mu and Kappa values
r = np.random.vonmises(mu, kappa, 1000)

# Adjust Von-Mises curve from fitted data
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num=501)
y = np.exp(kappa*np.cos(x-mu))/(2*np.pi*i0(kappa))

# Adjuste x limits and labels
plt.xlim(-np.pi, np.pi)
plt.xticks([-np.pi, -np.pi/2, 0, np.pi/2, np.pi],
labels=[r'$-\pi$ (0º)', r'$-\frac{\pi}{2}$ (90º)', '0 (180º)', r'$\frac{\pi}{2}$ (270º)', r'$\pi$'])

# Plot adjusted Von-Mises function as line
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=2, color='red', zorder=3)

# Plot distribution
plt.hist(r, density=True,  bins=20, alpha=1, edgecolor='white')
plt.title('Slaty Cleavage Strike', fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)



# From the data above (mu, kappa, x and y):

theta = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num=50, endpoint=False)
radii = np.exp(kappa * np.cos(theta - mu)) / (2 * np.pi * i0(kappa))

# Display width
width = (2 * np.pi) / 50

# Construct ax with polar projection
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

# Set Orientation
ax.set_theta_zero_location('E')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_xlim(-np.pi/1.000001, np.pi/1.000001)  # workaround for a weird issue
ax.set_xticks([-np.pi/1.000001 + i/8 * 2*np.pi/1.000001 for i in range(8)])

# Plot bars:
bars = ax.bar(x=theta, height=radii, width=width)
# Plot Line:
line = ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=1, color='red', zorder=3)

# Grid settings
ax.set_rgrids(np.arange(.5, 1.6, 0.5), angle=0, weight='black')


plt.show()
```

Comment: I edited the question to make myself a little bit more clear about whether or not X ranges  from `[-pi,pi]` or `[0,2pi]`. Thanks a lot, but we still have to figure it out how to wrap the Von-Mises line around the unit circle.

Comment: You mean the red line? It might look strange but it kind of already is where it's supposed to be (0 just is at the center)

Comment: Shouldn't the red line be at zero (zero probability) for all other angles (directions) except for where the distribution strikes out? Just like the first plot of the question

Comment: It IS at 0, 0 is the center of the circle. The image you posted just has a gap at the center. You can get a similar effect with `ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5)`