# Matplotlib Polar Plot - Overriding major tic axis labels

Tags: matplotlib

Using a list with 360 entries, I am creating a polar chart with MatplotLib. This works nicely:

%matplotlib widget

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')
for rad in np.arange(0, (2 * np.pi), 2 * np.pi / 360):
    plt.polar(rad, random.random()*10, marker='.', markersize=2, color='green')
plt.show()
```

But I get degrees 0 through 360, with 0 at "3pm". What I want is to have labels at 3, 6, 9 and 12 be, respectively, Front, Right, Back and Left. And then I want to rotate the whole thing so that Front as at 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ax.set_theta_zero_location` with whatever direction you want (East,West,South,North) to change the location of the origin `0`. See doc [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/projections_api.html) and example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906510/rotate-theta-0-on-matplotlib-polar-plot).

See example below with the code you provided:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')
for rad in np.arange(0, (2 * np.pi), 2 * np.pi / 360):
    plt.polar(rad, np.random.random()*10, marker='.', markersize=2, color='green')
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N") #Set location to "North" to have 0 on top
plt.show()
```

And the output returns:

[image]

**EDIT**:

To change the ticks to "Front",etc, you can use: `ax.set_xticklabels(['Front','','Left','','Back','','Right'])`

See output below:

[image]

Comment: And how do I change the labels from 0 degrees to "Front", etc?

Comment: You could use: `ax.set_xticklabels(['Front','','Left','','Back','','Right'])`. See edit in the answer.